# ReactJS: Module parse failed ',,.../index.js' you may need appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I change the default index.js file location generated from `create-react-app`.

This is my directory structure :-

```
|--main-project
   |--client
      |--components
      |--pages
      |--public
      |--App.js
      |--index.js
   |--mode_modules
   |--server
   |--package.json
   |
   |-- /react small files like package-lock.json and stuff
```

My corresponding **path.js** configuration in node_module/react-scripts/config

```
module.exports = {
  dotenv: resolveApp('.env'),
  appPath: resolveApp('.'),
  appBuild: resolveApp('build'),
  appPublic: resolveApp('public'),
  appHtml: resolveApp('client/public/index.html'),
  appIndexJs: resolveApp('client/index.js'),
  appPackageJson: resolveApp('package.json'),
  appSrc: resolveApp('src'),
  yarnLockFile: resolveApp('yarn.lock'),
  testsSetup: resolveApp('src/setupTests.js'),
  appNodeModules: resolveApp('node_modules'),
  publicUrl: getPublicUrl(resolveApp('package.json')),
  servedPath: getServedPath(resolveApp('package.json')),
// These properties only exist before ejecting:
 ownPath: resolveOwn('.'),
 ownNodeModules: resolveOwn('node_modules'), // This is empty on npm 3
};
```

I have changed appHtml and appIndexJS path

How to tell the default jsx loader to see these files ?

Comment: Have you ejected your app using `npm run eject` to run the react-scripts eject? You should consider ejecting and the edit the newly created main-project/config/paths.js rather than editing the paths.js of the node module

Comment: OR, don't screw about with the default configuration of create-react-app because otherwise you'll be in for a world of pain. Ejecting is not solution to this issue. The easiest solution is to put that file back and restructure how your app is called. IMO, obviously :)

Comment: @FinbarrO'B 
The problem is the default  '.jsx ' reader is not reading my newly relocated files .
Will doing `npm run eject` and then changing paths on the corresponding `module.exports` function work ?

Comment: @Andy Didn't get you ? IMO ??

Comment: IMO is In My Opinion. You need to understand that ejecting is __not reversible__, and you will remove the single build dependency from your project. It's not a decision to take lightly and for such a small thing.

Comment: @Andy Okay.  So any suggestions how can i make the default '.jsx ' parser to redirect to my new file structure and read that ? 
That is the main problem here , my new index.js file is not parsed by due to change in location. (I don't want the default file structure of `create-react-app` .)

Comment: You have 2 choices. Either accept the file structure/folder name convention of create-react-app, or eject like Finbarr suggested but cause yourself lots of additional problems. Personally I would go for option A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `appSrc:resolveApp('src')` to `appSrc:resolveApp('client')`

Everthing should work fine then !

**Its not necessary to use the default file structure, you can configure it as discussed above.**